# Shrink an HTML table containing images proportionally according to screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

Consider the following code.  How can I implement the table in a responsive manner such that on a large screen the table height and width is equal to the sum if the images (e.g. 600x600) and on a smaller screen such as a mobile device the table shrinks the images proportionally.  For example, on an iPhone where the screen width is 320 pixels I want the table to scale down to 320x320 while preserving the image aspect ratio.

```
<HTML>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="table"
    <table style="height: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img id="topleft" src="300x300.png">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img id="topright" src="300x300.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img id="bottomleft" src="300x300.png">
            </td>
            <td>
                <img id="bottomright" src="300x300.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an image showing how the above code renders in a mobile Safari browser.

[image]

Comment: [Adaptive images](http://adaptive-images.com/) might help you! Also, using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) will help as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set table width to 100% and td and img widths to rougly 49% (to keep the border) if you have 2 images per row. Additionally, if you might have images smaller than the possible screen size, use something like `img {max-width: 49%;}`

Comment: That solution breaks on a desktop where the screen width is wider than the height.  It would need some sort of a left and right margin perhaps.  Hmm...

Comment: It shouldn't break... unless you use height: 100%. Define only widths and the heights will auto adjust.

Comment: Ah, so the images are smaller than the half of the screen. It means you used `max-width`. One option is to force scale them by using `width` instead (like I wrote in my answer) but that would make images look ugly (interpolated)... The other, better, solution would be to break up tables and allow more than 2 images per row for such screens (if your app is planned to do that, of course).

Comment: Actually the screen shot is the result of using "width".  The app requires a 2x2 grid so unfortunately I can't simply add images to the row.  I'm starting to think that I need to solve this with javascript.

Comment: Then it seems like you have `position: relative` on td elements... try `width: 99%` please.

Comment: Is there a live version of that page somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive table dimension can be tricky.  First thing I would recommend is to put table inside of a div with attribute as `position: relative` and then control your margins and size this way.

```
<div id="myCont" style="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Hello! </td>
            <td> Aloha! </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Goodbye! </td>
            <td> Aloha! </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then some css:

```
#myCont {
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;
}
#myCont table {
    width: 100%;
}
#myCont table tr td {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.imgCls {
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you then set table to `<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`, you're going to have a lot easier time getting the accurate dimensions and a "clear slate" to start with.

Also, img tags will ALWAYS respect the aspect ratio if you only set the `width` attribute.

For this, I might recommend a jQuery solution.

```
<img class="imgCls" src="/path/to/img.png" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imgw = $('.imgCls').parent('td').css('width');
    $('.imgCls').css('width',imgw);
});
</script>
```

Something like this should work as long as the images with the `imgCls` class are (or desired to be) uniform in width, the `var imgw` will take the width of the first `.imgCls` it finds.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to try with this css code:

```
img{ width: 49%;  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xeSLA/